# Alternate name for one-to-one vs one-to-many

Tags: terminology, cardinality

Are there generally accepted computer science terms for one-to-one  and one-to-many relationships? Something similar to the terms "aggregation", "generalization", and "association," but strictly pertaining to the cardinality of the relationship?

Comment: Pretty sure that this should belong to Programmers Stack...

Answer (score 4):

From everything I've ever read, `one-to-one`, `one-to-many`, etc. are the accepted ways of referring to these relationships. They are very self descriptive of what they're about.